# How to fix "angular ionic pwa application custom keyboard (like gboard) not working on ios?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, gboard

I have developed an application in ionic/angular and it works fine in both devices but when I export as PWA app in ios/safari if user do not use ios default keyboard, he/she cant type and fill input fields and cant have interaction with the keyboard to change it.